# Error al llenar un array de forma manual en kotlin java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: array, kotlin

[image: Error al terminar de ingresar un arreglo de forma manual en Kotlin]

Hola buenas noches con todos, cada vez que lleno un array en Kotlin de forma manual me sale este tipo de error, sabran de alguna manera como solucionarlo

```
import java.lang.System.`in`
import java.util.Scanner
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val scanner  = Scanner(System.`in`)
val Teclado  = Scanner(System.`in`)
var Valor=Teclado.nextInt()
print("Igrese el Tamaño del arreglo: ")
val Tamanio = scanner.nextInt()
var Silvia=IntArray(Tamanio)
for (Iteracion in 1..Tamanio){
print("Posicion[ $Iteracion ]: ")
Silvia[Iteracion]= Teclado.nextInt()
}

}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: los arreglos empiezan en 0 por ende la ultima poscion es 9, debes colocar de 0...tamanio y a la hora del print solo sumarle 1 para que te de igual de 1 a 10 en pantalla

Comment: Está mal la forma en que estás recorriendo el array, como bien sabes todos los arrays empiezan desde 0, y a la sentencia for le estás diciendo que inicie desde la posición 1 y no en la 0, espero te sirva de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error significa que no existe un elemento en la posición que intentas acceder.

Las posiciones de los arreglos comienzan desde el 0. Por lo tanto, en un arreglo de 10 elementos, la posición 10 no existe.

Puedes restarle uno a la variable cuando intentas acceder, así:

```
Silvia[Iteracion - 1]
```

O usar la propiedad [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) del arreglo.

```
for (Iteracion in Silvia.indices){
    print("Posicion[ $Iteracion ]: ")
    Silvia[Iteracion] = Teclado.nextInt()
}
```